# How do I monitor the lock on a file to see when it is released? [C++]

Tags: c++, winapi, file

I am looking for a way to create a program in *unmanaged* c++ that waits until a file is unlocked (as in it is no longer in use) and than does something.  I have had no luck locating how to do this, any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE: I may have answered my own question, see below and tell me what you think..

UPDATE: All that really matters is that the file is writable, it doesn't matter if it is still in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution to my problem, does anyone see a problem with this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
void main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    if (argc < 2 || argc > 2) {
        return;
    }

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open(argv[1], ios_base::app);
    while (!myfile.is_open()) { Sleep(100); myfile.open(argv[1], ios_base::app); }
    myfile.close();

    // file should now be unlocked..
}
```

Thanks again!

UPDATE: Changed the code to be more complete.

Comment: Doesn't look like it's waiting?

Comment: I don't think is_open blocks, if that's what you're hoping for.

Comment: No, it doesn't, I have a Sleep(100) in the version that I am using.

Comment: Standard C++ has no file locking functionality.

Comment: That's true, but most operating systems do, and this only needs to run on XP.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will wait without wasting cpu cycles.

```
HANDLE h = FindFirstChangeNotification("C:\Path to folder holding file", FALSE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE);

while(true)
{
    if (CheckLockFile("C:\Path to file"))
    {
        // Do something
        break;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(h, APPROPRIATE_TIMEOUT_VALUE);
    FindNextChangeNotification(h);
}

bool CheckLockFile(char* FilePath)
{
    HANDLE fh = CreateFile(FilePath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0,NULL);
    if (fh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return false; 
    }
    CloseHandle(fh);

    return true;
}
```

This assumes the application with the lock on the file has it open for writing.

Comment: This is not exactly waterproof: FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE will not trigger when a file that was opened read-only is closed; it only works when the disk cache is sufficiently flushed; and notifications can get lost when the system is very busy.

Answer (score 1):

Create a loop that calls [::CreateFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) every 5 seconds until it succeeds.  Pass 0 in the dwShareMode argument, to make sure there are no other process that have the file opened.

Comment: Will this stomp on the file that I'm trying to monitor?

Comment: That depends on the dwCreationDisposition you specify. If you choose OPEN_EXISTING, it will only open an existing file.  The name CreateFile refers to creating a handle to the file, not necessarily creating a file itself.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to access the file after another program has released the lock.  UNIX (and Cygwin) gives you this behavior by simply locking the file.

Using something like `ScopeGuard` can make `File_locker` unnecessary, but if you're not using `ScopeGuard`, go like this:

UNIX:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include "sys/file.h" //flock
#include "sys/fcntl.h" //open

class File_locker {
    int file_descriptor;
  public:
    File_locker(std::string filename)
    {
        // you can use errno to determine why the open/flock failed,
        // but this is a demo, not production code

        file_descriptor = ::open(filename.c_str(), O_RDWR);
        if (file_descriptor < 0)
            throw std::runtime_error((std::string("unable to open file ")
                + filename).c_str());
        if (::flock(file_descriptor, LOCK_EX)) {
            ::close(file_descriptor);
            throw std::runtime_error((std::string("unable to flock file ")
                + filename).c_str());
        }
    }
    ~File_locker()
    {
        ::flock(file_descriptor, LOCK_UN); // don't forget to unlock
        ::close(file_descriptor);
    }
};
```

In Windows it appears you have to poll the file.

Windows:

```
#include <string>
#include "windows.h"

class File_locker {
    HANDLE file_handle;
    static const int MAX_TRIES = 10;
    static const int SLEEP_INTERVAL = 500;

  public:
    File_locker(std::string filename)
    {
        // you can use GetLastError() to determine why the open failed,
        // but this is a demo, not production code
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TRIES; ++i) {
            file_handle = ::CreateFile(filename.c_str(),
                                       GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                       0,
                                       NULL,
                                       OPEN_EXISTING,
                                       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                       NULL);
            if (file_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                return;
            ::Sleep(SLEEP_INTERVAL);
            }
            throw std::runtime_error((std::string("unable to open file ")
                + filename).c_str());
    }
    ~File_locker()
    {
        ::CloseHandle(file_handle);
    }
};
```

Use it like so:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>

// .. define File_locker, as above

int main()
{
    try {
        File_locker fl("filename.txt");
        // once fl is constructed, nobody else has the file locked
        std::fstream file("filename.txt");
        // ...
        return 0;
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error& ex)
    {
        // just bail
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that under windows, CreateFile() won't block on locks?

Answer (score -1):

Simply use System locking File Notifications

Comment: Could you elaborate?  Perhaps a link or an example?