# How can i wait until a file will not be locked(not be in use)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this code in a button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WatchDirectory();
    StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(userVideosDirectory + "\\UploadedVideoFiles.txt",true);
    w.WriteLine(fileforupload);
    w.Close();                    
    uploadedFilesList.Add(fileforupload);                   
    Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new Youtube_Uploader(uploadedFilesList[0]);
}
```

Now what i want to do is to WatchDirectory in this method i'm watching a file once the file is not locked anymore not in use then continue in the button click event.

Somehow i need to make while loop or something when calling the WatchDirectory and when the file is not locked anymore then continue to the rest of the code:

This code in the button click do it only when the file is not locked/in use anymore:

```
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(userVideosDirectory + "\\UploadedVideoFiles.txt",true);
w.WriteLine(fileforupload);
w.Close();                    
uploadedFilesList.Add(fileforupload);                   
Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new Youtube_Uploader(uploadedFilesList[0]);
```

And this is the WatchDirectory method:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher;
private void WatchDirectory()
{
    watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = userVideosDirectory;
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size;
    watcher.Filter = "*.mp4";
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    var info = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
    fileforupload = info.FullName;
    if (IsFileLocked(fileforupload) == false)
    {
          watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
          watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
 }
```

And the IsFileLocked method.

```
public bool IsFileLocked(string filename)
{
     bool Locked = false;
     try
     {
        FileStream fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                  FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        fs.Close();
     }
     catch (IOException ex)
     {
          Locked = true;
     }

     return Locked;
 }
```

The logic should be something like this:

Calling WatchDirectory then watching the file:

```
File is locked
File is locked
File is locked
File is locked
File is not locked and not in use
Now do the rest of the code in the button click event
```

And while it's checking the file locked or not enable false the button1 once it's not locked anymore enable it true.

Comment: Try finding the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879530/how-do-i-monitor-the-lock-on-a-file-to-see-when-it-is-released-c

Comment: As I understand, there is API mechanism to monitor directiory/file changes but not handles. So the only way for you is sleep-based polling.